# Copy or mark lines having misspelled words in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, clipboard, copy-paste, spell-checking

I have a text file with several lines and Spell Checked the entire document using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Now, I want to copy all the lines having misspellings into the clipboard for analysis.

I could not find a way to at least bookmark the lines with misspelled/unrecognized words so that I can copy them using `Search > Bookmark > Copy Bookmarked Lines`.

Comment: Are you using [this](https://github.com/Predelnik/DSpellCheck/wiki/Manual#Settings_Dialog) spell checker?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness: Yes, I am.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you could record a macro for this. In practice It will not work since there seems to exist a bug with notepad++ calling for plugins while recording macros. [See here](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/3046).

I suggest you to use "Python Script" plugin. You can install it from `Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager`

Once installed, define a new python script like this:

```
Editor.gotoLine(editor, 0)
notepad.runPluginCommand('DSpellCheck', 'Find Next Misspelling')

first_start = Editor.getSelectionStart(editor)
first_end = Editor.getSelectionEnd(editor)

if first_start != first_end:
    while True:
        notepad.menuCommand(MENUCOMMAND.SEARCH_TOGGLE_BOOKMARK)

        sel_start = Editor.getSelectionStart(editor)
        notepad.runPluginCommand('DSpellCheck', 'Find Next Misspelling')
        sel_start_new = Editor.getSelectionStart(editor)

        if sel_start_new == first_start: break

        line_sel_start = Editor.lineFromPosition(editor, sel_start)
        line_sel_start_new = Editor.lineFromPosition(editor, sel_start_new)

        if line_sel_start == line_sel_start_new: Editor.gotoLine(editor, 1+line_sel_start)
```

When executed, It will bookmark all lines with unrecognized words.

Then you will be able to do a `Copy Bookmarked Lines`